# In Web Audio, why does contextTime lag currentTime by more than baseLatency?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

As I understand it, the audio context has:

- `.currentTime`, the time at the beginning of the next schedule-able 128-sample frame buffer (previous buffers having already been sent)
- `.baseLatency`, the time it takes to transfer scheduled audio from WebAudio land to the OS
- `.getOutputTimestamp().contextTime`, a timestamp for the sample frame currently being handed to the OS

By this understanding, `context.getOutputTimestamp().contextTime` should never be less than `context.currentTime - context.baseLatency`.

But it is! In my tests in Chrome on a fast MacBook it is less than that by as much as -0.025s. That's > 1000 sample frames behind.

```js
const context = new AudioContext();

// Let the audio clock settle
setTimeout(function() {
    const currentTime = context.currentTime;
    const contextTime = context.getOutputTimestamp().contextTime;
    console.assert(
        contextTime > (currentTime - context.baseLatency),
        'contextTime', contextTime,
        'currentTime', currentTime,
        'baseLatency', context.baseLatency,
        'contextTime - (currentTime - baseLatency)', contextTime - (currentTime - context.baseLatency)
    );
}, 1000);
```

Are my assumptions about what it should do skewed, or is the API lying to me about it's baseLatency?

Comment: This is a case of RTFM. The Web Audio spec actually makes this very clear in the notes under the section getOutputTimestamp (https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#dom-audiocontext-getoutputtimestamp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumptions are skewed. The Web Audio spec makes this clear in the notes under the section getOutputTimestamp (https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#dom-audiocontext-getoutputtimestamp).

The third bullet in my question is wrong. `.getOutputTimestamp().contextTime` is **not** a timestamp for the sample frame currently being handed *to* the audio driver as I state in the question. It is, as it's name suggests, a timestamp for the sample frame currently being output *from* the audio driver.

As @Raymond hints at in his answer, the correct latency to compare this timestamp against is `outputLatency` (which is not implemented as of Jan 2019).

Answer (score 1):

The `.baseLatency` is basically the number of audio samples need by the WebAudio implementation to work smoothly.  It can be as lows as 128 (but no lower) and can be significantly larger (8000 or more).  For Macs, the default value is 256.  This is used to smooth out any jittering of the audio clock.  Mac's have very low jitter so 256 (or 128) works well. Linux machines tend not to be as accurate so 512 or higher is used. (For chrome.)

This does not include any additional buffering that might be between webaudio and the browser audio system and the browser to the OS, and from the OS to the actual output device. (I understand Bluetooth devices can sometimes have huge delays.)

There is an `outputLatency` attribute that is supposed to show this, but AFAIK, it's not implemented in any browser yet.

Comment: Ok... so does that mean that context.getOutputTimestamp().contextTime is giving us the timestamp of a frame being processed AFTER one of those additional buffers? If not, contextTime + baseLatency should reasonably be greater than currentTIme, no?

Comment: There was a diagram of how this all worked during the spec discussion but I can't seem to find it.  It did a pretty good job of explaining the relationship.  Once I find it, I'll link to it here.  I hope that would clarify every thing.  Perhaps that should have been part of the spec itself.

Comment: So in the absence of outputLatency support (except for Firefox) can a reasonable estimate be made using getOutputTimestamp (and possibly combined with other Web Audio API features)?

Comment: `getOutputTimeStamp` is intended to help you synchronize WebAudio's audio context clock to the system clock. (They could be on different clock sources and can drift.)  So I don't think that will help.  Consider the case where you have a bluetooth headset or wifi speakers.  There could be a pretty significant delay there which wouldn't be captured.  You need `outputLatency` to tell you that.